# Unexpected behavior with Angular Material's nested tree with dynamic nodes

Tags: angular, angular-material

I implemented a nested Angular Material nested tree component that loads children nodes dynamically using observables.

Basic functionality seems to work but I am not sure why it seems to generate children node twice whenever I expand a node.

Hard to explain in words, so a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-dynamic-nested-tree) can be seen here with more details.

Q: When you expand "Item 1", why console prints "loaded" twice instead of once?

Comment: If you open browser console it only occurs once. This might be due to StackBlitz loading duplicate instances of the project or caching. Does it happen in your standard project? Note: nothing appears to be wrong with your code, and it is only generating the single instance if Item1 as far as I can see (console log in your .subscribe() function and it will show the data)

Comment: thanks for feedback @Z.Bagley. yes, it happens on my actual project code. chrome's native dev console show up twice as well (console line is prefixed with the rounded "2" icon). i suspect is has something to do with how CDK's NestedTreeControl works but not sure (still need to t/shoot).

Comment: Not sure why exactly, but it appears that its proc'ing changes twice (not actually generating two instances). A minimal workaround would be to set a flag to change the change type and only log when it actually is different to ensure one proc per change. You're clearly getting a single subscription, a single connection, a single nested node, so it is likely only creating a duplicate emitter somewhere. Sorry I didn't see anything deeper.

Comment: I may have actually caught the reason... it's detecting changes after the children node are loaded which proc's the DataTree's change detection! I'll branch your SB to show you that if you do what I commented it actually prevents the children from updating. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-dynamic-nested-tree-nqwnjn

Comment: I've posted this as an issue on angular's github, along with some additional info on why this can happen. still no solution. https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18682